# Query nearest neighbors of a point in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kdtree

I want to index points like:

(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)

and then retrieve the k nearest neighboors.

I'm not finding that functionality in Elastic Search REST api, anyone knows how to add and query n-dimensional points using Elastic Search REST api or the Elastic Search java client? (I can't use Lucene because it has not a REST api).

Thanks.

Comment: But Solr is OK?

Comment: Yes, its ok, has Solr that functionality unrestricted to n dimensional points?

Comment: The PointType in Solr is n-dimensional, so while I haven't tried it myself, it seems it should be possible.

Comment: Hi, I need some example or something more specific to accept that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't an answer, it's a comment to explore the feature you're requesting further.

Comment: Hi, this recent issue tells me that the feature is not present in Solr: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11077

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [vector-scoring](https://github.com/MLnick/elasticsearch-vector-scoring) plugin. The example seems to perform cosine similarity but it might be extendable to other distance metrics as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://github.com/opendistro-for-elasticsearch/k-NN. 
This will exactly serve your purpose to find  nearest neighbors to the given query vector